# Operations or Checks needed on the table where million records are getting inserted daily?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Activities to take care of when millions of records are getting insert daily in a table in the sql server

Comment: so what's the question? And which version of SQL Server are you using? You selected 2...

Comment: Are you asking if there are standard maintenance actions that a DBA should do when millions of records are getting inserted daily?

Comment: All the things you'd do for any database, but things that require extra attention for a high throughput DB are backups, DBCC checks, transaction log file backups, disk space checks